# sed replace pattern with newline character

Tags: sed, wildcards, replace

I'm trying to replace a specific "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in the httpd.conf file.

Given the file has multiple line with the same pattern I thought I would do a multiline pattern to replace it... Unless sed has a way to choose when it should replace the pattern.

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

I was replacing single lines with:

```
sudo sed -i 's|DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"|DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/test"|' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But I'm not sure how to do it if there's multiple lines

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how your sed line will change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`, can you elaborate?  Also are you looking for the `g` flag which tells sed to replace all matches and not just the first?  `'s/pattern/replace/g'`

Comment: Actually as I was writing the question I found out you can choose a specific line to replace: `sudo sed -i '151s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' httpd.conf` works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

`sed` has many ways to do this.  For example, with the `c`hange command:

```
sed --in-place '/^AllowOverride All/c\
AllowOverride None\n' httpd.conf
```

Or, with a better use of `s`ubstitute:

```
sed --in-place '/^AllowOverride/s/All/None/'
```

The latter can be transliterated as 'On lines which begin with `AllowOverride`, replace the first instance of `All` with `None`'.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out you can specify a line number to replace a string:

```
sudo sed -i '151s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' httpd.conf
```

works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this.  What if it's on a different line the next time you try it?  If you have to manually parse the file to find the correct line number you might as well just manually change the config while you are in there.